# Question on Uniform Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question that I need help. The question is:

Let $f$ be uniformly continuous on $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Suppose there exists a constant $k$ such that $f(x) \geq k \gt 0$ for all $x$ in $A$. Prove that $\dfrac{1}{f}$ is also uniformly continuous on $A$.

I was able to show that $\dfrac1f$ is continuous but I have difficulty showing whether $A$ is a closed interval.

Just wondering if I'm on the right track for my proof?

Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't tried this problem, but to me, it screams using the definition.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to try to use the theorem that a continuous function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous. This is not the way to go about this question since you really have no idea what the domain of definition of $f$ and there is no reason in the world why that would be a closed interval.

Instead, follow the definition of uniform continuity. Start out with explicitly writing down what it would mean to show that $1/f$ is uniformly continuous. Then remember that $f$ is given to be uniformly continuous and try to use that in order to show what you want to show. Somewhere you will find it useful to know that $f(x)\ge k >0$ for all $x\in A$. That should indicate to you you are on the right track.

Alternatively, the composition of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous. So, (and this is a much shorter solution but it may obscure what is actually going on here) can you express the function $1/f(x)$ as the composition of two functions? make sure you use the condition that $f(x)\ge k >0$ for all $x\in A$ to properly define the other uniformly continuous function!

Comment: I have tried using the definition to solve. By playing around with the inquality, I choose epilson to be 1/k since it is more than 0. Will that be a valid argument? (:

Comment: not quite. To use the definition, start out with what it means for 1/f to be uniformly continuous. I.e., let $\varepsilon >0$. We are looking for blah blah blah.... Now, the epsilon is given. Find its $\delta$ (using $k$ somehow).

Comment: Hmm.. It's not possible to find a delta. But I've tried to link the epsilon for both f and 1/f together with the help of the inequality. Will that be sufficient? (: